# Custom JSON Deserializer for badly formatted JSON

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to deserialize some poorly formatted JSON.  when result data exists I get it back in the format:

```
[
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "result": {
            "17449": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "17449",
                    "type_title": "Relation"
                },
                "children": false
            },
            "17451": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "17451",
                    "type_title": "Relation"
                },
                "children": false
            },
            "19059": {
                "data": {
                    "id": "19059",
                    "type_title": "Relation"
                },
                "children": false
            }
        },
        "error": null,
        "id": 5
    }
]
```

When there is no result data I get:

```
[
    {
        "jsonrpc": "2.0",
        "result": [],
        "error": null,
        "id": 5
    }
]
```

So when I get data, I can parse that into a `Dictionary<string,dataObject>` but when I get an empty array back the Jsson Deserializer throws an exception trying to deserialize the empty array into a Dictionary.

I know I need to override the ReadJson method, but I'm not sure quite how to identify the empty array and what to return if I find one.

Here's where I'm at:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    object retVal = new Object();
    if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
    {
        #Somehow identify an empty array and return the right object (an empty Dictionary)
    }
    else
    {
        retVal = serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

I could use some help in completing ReadJson to meet my needs.

Comment: can you ask that the data source be changed to return an empty object instead of an empty array in that situation?

Comment: I'm trying, but I have very little control over the datasource, it's beyond my immediate control, so in the short term I have to work with what I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In prioritized order, here's how you should fix this:

1. Try to get the output changed, meaning that whoever constructs this json should decide if they want to return an array or a dictionary, and not both
2. Use a custom deserializer

Here's the custom deserializer, note that when it detects an array it simply assumes this array is empty, it does not in any way try to deserialize the contents of the array.

```
public class DictionaryOrEmptyArray : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            return new Dictionary<string, dataObject>();
        return token.ToObject<Dictionary<string, dataObject>>();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType == typeof(Dictionary<string, dataObject>);
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You would attach this to your property like this:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(DictionaryOrEmptyArray))]
public Dictionary<string, dataObject> Result { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and the code.  Works perfectly.  Will still campaign for option 1 though!